# Is there a way to optimize this code so that I avoid outOfMemory error?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, arraylist, tree

My overall project is to create a tree and use Huffman coding to encode and decode a given file. I am at the point where I need to decode my file. To do this, i am having to step through my Huffman Tree until I reach a bottom most leaf and then return the Byte represented by that leaf. I traverse the tree according to the bit string given to the method. AKA if the current bit is 1, I go to childOne in the tree and so forth. The problem is that I keep getting an `outOfMemory` error. Is there any way to optimize this code so that it won't use as much memory?

```
    public static int decode(List<Integer> bitArray, HuffmanNode root, int startingPosition,
                          ArrayList<Byte> finalArray)
    {
    HuffmanNode childOne;
    HuffmanNode childZero;
    int currentBit = bitArray.get(startPosition);
    byte newByte;

            childOne = root.getChildOne();
            childZero = root.getChildZero();
            if(childOne == null && childZero == null)
            {
               finalArray.add(root.getByteRepresented()); 
               return startPosition;
            } 
            else if(currentBit == 1)
            {
                startPosition++;
                startPosition = decode(bitArray,childOne,startPosition,finalArray);
            }
            else
            {
                startPosition++;
                startPosition = decode(bitArray,childZero,startPosition,finalArray);
            }

         return startPosition;

}
```

I am needing to know the place in the bitArray that it ended as well as put the specified Byte into an array, so that is why I am putting the Byte into the array within the method and returning and int. Basically, is there any better way to get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. Change recursion to iteration..

```
temp = root;
childOne = temp.getChildOne();
childZero = temp.getChildZero();
while(childOne != null && childZero != null) {
  currentBit = bitArray.get(startPosition++);
  if (currentBit == 1) {
    temp = childOne;
  } else {
    temp = childZero;
  }
  childOne = temp.getChildOne();
  childZero = temp.getChildZero();
}
```

Comment: Oh ok. I guess that does make sense. This is just for a homework assignment and it was recommended that I use a recursive algorithm.

Comment: Alright. It won't be as nice as algorithm, but it obviously wont' work without changing. Thanks!

Comment: @GabrielleLee- Recursion is an elegant and simple to understand approach, but not always efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how big things are, but I don't think you need recursion.  Can't you do what you need with a loop like this one:

```
while (curNode.isNotLeaf())
{
  if (currentBit == 1) curNode = curNode.getChildOne();
  else curNode = curNode.getChildZero();
  currentBit = nextBit;
}

addByte(curNode, bigArray)
```

so you go through your bits in this loop, adding represented bytes when you get to leaves, and then continue on -- no need for all the stack frames recursion involves.

Answer (score 0):

Also, consider using lower-level data structures like `java.util.BitSet` instead of `List<Integer>` and `java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream` instead of `ArrayList<Byte>`.

Answer (score 0):

If recursion was your issue you would most likely be getting stack overflow errors. As you are running out of memory I would suggest you look at:

- Be sure to discard `bitArray` and `finalArray` after each call.
- Use a stream to output to.
- Use a `BitSet` for the bitArray.
- Make sure you are not accidentally making loops in your tree.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at compressed bit set implementation like
OpenBitSet (Lucene)
http://code.google.com/p/javaewah/
http://www.censhare.com/en/aktuelles/censhare-labs/yet-another-compressed-bitset